# d3 stacked bar chart not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, html, csv, d3.js

I have a stacked bar chart created using d3.

I am trying to update my bar graph with data from a different .csv using buttons.

Here is my code so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
 
#title {
 font-family: serif;
 font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px gray;
}

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.exit {
 opacity: 0;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
 <p id="title">Server/Client Relationship with Groups Algorithm</p>
 <div id="option">
  <input name="updateButton"
         type="button"
         value="Update"
         onclick="updateData()" />
  <input name="revertButton"
         type="button"
         value="Revert"
         onclick="revertData()" />
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 1100 - margin.left - margin.right, 
    height = 700 - margin.top - margin.bottom; 

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


d3.csv("before.csv", function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Servers"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    var y0 = 0;
    d.ages = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
    d.total = d.ages[d.ages.length - 1].y1;
  });


  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Servers; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Number of Clients");

  var servers = svg.selectAll(".servers")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.Servers) + ",0)"; });

  servers.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
      

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });
      
      
});


function updateData() {
 d3.csv("after.csv", function(error, data) {
 color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Servers"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    var y0 = 0;
    d.ages = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
    d.total = d.ages[d.ages.length - 1].y1;
  });


  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Servers; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);
  
  
  
   svg.select(".x.axis").transition()
         .duration(750)
         .call(xAxis);
      svg.select(".y.axis").transition()
         .duration(750)
         .call(yAxis);
                  
  var servers = svg.selectAll(".servers")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.Servers) + ",0)"; });
      
     
      
  servers.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
    .enter().append("rect")
    .transition()
      servers.attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
      
     
 });
}

function revertData() {
  d3.csv("before.csv", function(error, data) {
 color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Servers"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    var y0 = 0;
    d.ages = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
    d.total = d.ages[d.ages.length - 1].y1;
  });


  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Servers; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);
  
  
   svg.select(".x.axis").transition()
         .duration(750)
         .call(xAxis);
      svg.select(".y.axis").transition()
         .duration(750)
         .call(yAxis);
         
         
   var servers = svg.selectAll(".servers")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.Servers) + ",0)"; });
      
  servers.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
    .enter().append("rect")
    .transition()
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
  
  
 });
}

</script>
</body>
```

before.csv:

```html
Servers,Group 1,Group 2,Group 3,Group 4,Group 5,Group 6,Group 7,Group 8,Group 9,Group 10
Server 1,2,0,0,0,0,3,1,0,0,1
Server 2,1,0,2,0,0,0,2,1,1,0
Server 3,2,0,1,0,2,2,1,0,0,0
Server 4,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,2,1,0
Server 5,0,0,0,2,0,1,1,1,1,3
Server 6,5,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,3
Server 7,1,0,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,2
Server 8,3,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0
Server 9,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0
Server 10,1,2,1,1,0,2,2,2,0,1
Server 11,2,1,1,0,1,2,2,2,3,0
Server 12,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,2,1
```

after.csv:

```html
Servers,Group 1,Group 2,Group 3,Group 4,Group 5,Group 6,Group 7,Group 8,Group 9,Group 10
Server 1,0,0,0,0,0,13,0,0,0,0
Server 2,0,0,9,0,0,0,12,0,0,0
Server 3,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0
Server 4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,10,0
Server 5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11
Server 6,18,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Server 7,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0
Server 8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Server 9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Server 10,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Server 11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Server 12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

The problem is that whenever I press the buttons instead of it just displaying the new graph, the graphs overlap.

I'm fairly new to d3, so I was having trouble making it so that after a button press only the specified graph is displayed.

I've looked into different ways to use the transition, exit, and remove functions that are built into d3, but can't seem to get it right.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `body` to append. Add something like this:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

And change the variable to

```
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")....
```

After doing this, you can remove inside the elements inside using

```
$("#chart").empty();
```

in your `updateData` and `revertData` method.

Or if you want use only `d3js` code in a simply way which I use mostly

```
d3.select("svg").remove();
```

Comment: Thank you!  I got what I wanted now!